# workflow complete but output nothing, what I did wrong?

Tags: workflow, workflow-variable

I have 2 lists,
ankenlist: have some "anken", each anken have a "total", "total" mean amount of work to be done.
report: each record link to an anken, with a "Done",
I want to do like this: 
each time user add a record to "report" list, the associated anken in AnkenList will be updated with formula `UPDATE SET AnkenList.SumDone = SUM(Report.Done) WHERE AnkenList.AnkenID = Report.AnkenID`
I've create 2 lists and a workflow as below, but the workflow complete without any output.
Can you help me troubleshot it?
[image: 2 lists]
[image: workflow]
[image: run result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AnkedID in the list is a Lookup, so the string will never match the ID, because it will be 3;#anked1, so essentially you will never get to the conditional logic. You need to parse that out by returning the lookup value instead of returning "As String", return as lookup value.